# Animating the solution to an ODE in Julia

Tags: julia, visualization, ode, plots.jl, differentialequations.jl

I have a julia code:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots
using ParameterizedFunctions
plotly()
lorenz = @ode_def Lorenz begin
  dx = σ*(y-x)
  dy = ρ*x-y-x*z
  dz = x*y-β*z
end σ = 10. β = 8./3. ρ => 28.
u0 = [1., 5., 10.]
tspan = (0., 2.)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz, u0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob,save_timeseries=true)
plot(sol,vars=(:x,:y,:z))
```

Which results in:
[next plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykrK.png)

How can i animate this plot such that it would work either from REPL and jupyter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For DifferentialEquations.jl, there is a built-in animation function which can handle this. Unfortunately, I realized that I forgot to put it in the last release. When it's released, the syntax will be (simplifying your code a little bit):

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots
using ParameterizedFunctions
pyplot()
lorenz = @ode_def Lorenz begin
  dx = σ*(y-x)
  dy = ρ*x-y-x*z
  dz = x*y-β*z
end σ = 10. β = 8./3. ρ => 28.
u0 = [1., 5., 10.]
tspan = (0., 2.)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz, u0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob)
animate(sol,vars=(:x,:y,:z),xlims=(-20,20),ylims=(-15,20),zlims=(10,40))
```

A few things: `animate` can take any of the normal plot commands. However, it at each frame it plots from the beginning to the `i`th step, which means you may need to manually set the axis to make them not shift around. Another thing to note is that I switched backends to PyPlot. The Plotly backend cannot do animations. Maybe PlotlyJS can? [The animation function is documented here](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/plot#Animations-1).

Using that command will be by far the easiest way, but you can do it "more manually" using the [integrator interface](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/integrator). Essentially, you can just plot each step interval using this and get to the same place in the end. You'd have to use Plots.jl's [animation interface](https://juliaplots.github.io/animations/).

Edit: If you `Pkg.update()` this should now work.

Comment: would you care to explain the difference (pros/cons) between ``DifferentialEquations.jl`` built-in ``animate()`` vs ``@animate`` and ``@gif``. The latter are documented reasonably well in http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/ and http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/animations/. The syntax is different. And would you briefly describe how to save the gif? Do you just add ``filename = "mygif.gif"`` inside the ``animate()`` function? Thanks!

Comment: Also, some of the urls in your answer are no longer working.

Comment: fixed thanks. The DiffEq one just predated some of the Plots.jl things, which may be a bit more flexible these days.